# Removable singulariteis

Tags: complex-analysis

Can anyone give me a rigorus explantion to why simple roots are removable singularities in the function $f(z)=\text{sinh}\space z.$ I get the roots are $\pm n\pi i$, but why are $0, \pm \pi i$ and $\pm 2\pi i$ simple?

How about $\pm 3\pi i?$ Furthermore, it states in my answer solution that the function defined by:

$$h(z) = \frac{(z^2+\pi^2)(e^z-1)}{\text{sinh}\space z}$$ has the nearest pole to the origin of $\pm 3\pi i$, this also confuses me, why cant the poles infact be $\pm 2\pi i$ or $\pm \pi i$ or 0? Is it because they are removable? Then it goes back to my original question, why can these three roots be removable singularities in the first place?

I would appreciate the clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If $f(z_0)=0$, then $f'(z_0) \ne 0$,

   ($f'(z) = \cosh z$)

Hence $z_0$ is a simple zero of $f$.

2. If $h(z) = \frac{(z^2+\pi^2)(e^z-1)}{\text{sinh}\space z}$, then consider $g(z):=(z^2+\pi^2)(e^z-1)$.

We have $g(z)=0$ for $z \in Z:=\{0, \pm i \pi , \pm 2 \pi i\}$ and each $z \in Z$ is a simple zero of $g$.

From 1. and 2, we get: each $z \in Z$ is a removable singularity of $h$.

Comment: Few questions: wouldn't $\text{cosh} 3\pi i$  also not be equal to $0$? So why cant $\pm 3\pi$ i also be simple? The next question is, why is it that these roots being simple imply they are removable singularities of $h?$

Comment: 1. $ \cosh (3 \pi i)=1/2(e^{3 \pi}+e^{-3 \pi)}) \ne 0$. 2. If $f$ and $g$ are holomorphic and if $f$ and $g$ have both  a zero of order $n$ at $z_0$, then $h=f/g$ has a removable singularity at $z_0$.